# angular ui-grid enable disable row element based on flag

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using angular ui-grid to show list of rows from database table(Users).
I am doing a back end call and NodeJS fetches the data from DB and returns.
This data is being shown in angular ui-grid.

I want to enable or disable few html elements ., view/edit/delete based on the accessibility of the current user.
If the current user is ADMIN then all the links are enabled. If he is BASIC user then VIEW is enabled and EDIT and DELETE are disabled.
Project accessibility is also returned from the server . I just need to check this flag and disable/enable the links.
Please let me know , how to do this?

```
id  name    actions
1   AAA     view edit delete 
2   BBB     view edit delete 
3   CCC     view edit delete 
4   DDD     view edit delete 

  <div class="box">
        <div class="box-content box-table">
            <div ui-grid="gridUsers" ui-grid-pagination>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>


  $scope.gridUsers = {
            paginationPageSizes: [15, 30, 45],
            paginationPageSize: 15,
            enableColumnMenus: false,
            data: $scope.users,
            filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
            columnDefs: [{ field: 'id', displayName: 'Id', width: '20%'},
                { field: 'name', displayName: 'Name', width: '25%', enableFiltering: true},
                { name: 'Actions', displayName: 'Actions', width: '55%', cellTemplate:
                '<div class="grid-action-cell action-btns">'+
                '<span class="btn-small"><span style="color:#214c77;">view</span> </a>' +
                '<a ng-click="grid.appScope.edit(row.entity.id)" class="btn-small btn-link"><span style="color:#80bb41;">edit</span> </a>' +
                '<a ng-click="grid.appScope.delete(row.entity.id)" class="btn-small btn-link"> <span style="color:#e15829;">delete</span> </a>' 
                '</div>'}
            ]
        };


 Service.GetAllUsers(function (response) {
            if (response.length != 0) {
                $scope.users = response;
                $scope.gridUsers.data = $scope.users;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problema.
In order to resolve it, I call a function after retrieving columns :

```
        function updateColumnsDefs() {
                columnsDefs
                        .forEach(function(column) {
                            switch (column.field) {
                                case 'status' :
                                    columnVal = '<span ng-if="c.' + column.filterBy + '">{{c.' + column.filterBy + '}}</span>';
                                    column.cellTemplate = '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">' + columnVal + '</span></div>';
                                    break;
                                default :
                                    break;
                            }
         }
```

Look how I made a dynamic `cellTemplate` using `ng-if`.

After that, I apply the updated `columnsDefs` to gridOptions:

```
updateColumnsDefs();
vm.gridOptions = {
                    ...
                    columnDefs : columnsDefs,
                    ...
                };
```

You should pay attention if use lazy loading or filter. In that case remember to recall `updateColumnsDefs` every time your data model changes.

Comment: Thanks . Do i need to write updateColumnsDefs() definition after $scope.gridUsers definition ?

Comment: Function position does not matter. The only thing that matters is  updateColumnsDefs() function must be called before $scope.gridUsers initialization. My vm.gridOptions is equivalent to your $scope.gridUsers.

Comment: Ok . I need to move only the column which irequires enable/disable property ..right?

Comment: Note that I used a forEach. As I did, you can build a switch-case for filtering colums by field name.

Comment: Thanks Giaffa , this is not working when I am having 20 rows and change the page size to 5 . When moving to next page , the change is not applied.

Comment: It should works if you catch the pagination changed event and call into it the updateColumnsDefs() function.